# Mysql Database cant connect using "loclhost" But Can Connect using "127.0.0.1" Centos 7 (Cloudlinux)

Tags: mysql, centos, cpanel, whm

My OS: Centos 7 + CLOUDLINUX 7.7
When I Try To Login Mysql From Server

```
[root@server3 ~]# Mysql -u root -h localhost -P 3306  Working ok 
[root@server3 ~]# Mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306  Working Ok
```

But When I Use localhost on Hosted Domain "xyz.com" In there DB Host = "localhost"
It Not Connect, When I Change It to DB Host = "127.0.0.1" It Connect to Database

```
[root@server3 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

```
[root@server3 ~]# ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
```

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

any Idea For Fix?

Comment: What does it mean “not working”?

Comment: When xyz.com Domain Use DB Host ="localhost"
It did not Connect to Database but When Use DB Host="127.0.0.1" It Connect to Database

Comment: Dude. What does the error say. If it did connect you wouldn’t create this question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL connects over TCP/IP when using IP address (127.0.0.1), and uses socket file when used localhost. In your situation, I suppose you have mysql.sock in some special location and it is not available from CageFS inside. While `/var/lib/mysql/` is being used by default.

If so -  please add that directory to `/etc/cagefs/cagefs.mp` file then run `cagefsctl --remount-all`.

**And Problem Fix**